# Change the character image for a while in Python Pygame

Tags: python, timer, pygame

I am struggling with a problem I can't solve.

I want to **change the image of my character when the enemy hurts it**.

In **pseudocode**, it would be like this:

```
 *If enemy collides -> player close eyes and get red;*

  *After 0.50 seg -> player gets normal back again*
```

I tried to do it with Clock and Timers but it is very difficult. I only get changing the image, but not getting it back.

Any ideas?

### Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You'll find users more willing/able to help if you include the piece of code you're having trouble with and what you've tried so far. Please include a [Minimal, Complete Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

I would assume it's as easy as this. `pygame.time.set_timer(x, y)` basically creates an x event on the event stack every y milliseconds.

```
# Main game loop
while True:
    # display stuff and other parts of your game

    # replace this with whatever detection you have for collision
    if enemycollide:
        player.setSprite(1)
        pygame.time.set_timer(14, 500) # 500 milliseconds = .5 seconds

    # event handling
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == 14:
            player.setSprite(0)
            pygame.time.set_timer(14, 0) # Disable the timer
```